# Security access to EventLog

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

Is it possible to grant access to view the EventLog on Windows 2008 without giving Admin to a person?  If so how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a built in "Event Log Readers" group on the local machine. Add your users to that.

Of course, if you want to use an AD Group, then just add the AD Group to it. You could also use Group Policy Preferences to add users and groups to this group on your domain computers.